# Image Rotation is not originating from the center

Tags: html, css, transform

I have a close icon i want to rotate on its hover. Rotation happens but not from the center point. Tried `transform-origin :  50% 50%` and also with `center` property but still its not happening. Mentioned my code and also the link to the fiddle.

```
<div>

</div>



div{
  background:url('https://s32.postimg.org/4ze7aqwed/close.png') no-repeat;
  height:16px;
  width:16px;
  transform:rotate(0);
  transition:transform .3s ease
}
div:hover{
  transform:rotate(90deg)
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwuwfequ/)

Answer (score 3):

your problem seems to be that the image provide for the background is not the same size as the `<div>`. Rotation is done at 50% 50% by default, but since your the background image is covering the top left corner, when rotated 90º, it will end up in the top right corner.

I updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwuwfequ/1/) to have the div match the size of the image, which is 10px. Now it is properly rotating about the shared center between the background image and the div.

Edit. Also, as other have pointed out, you can center the background image with `background-position: center center;` which achieves the same thing, having a common center for your div and background image.

Comment: Actually, by default the transform origin is `0 0` not `50% 50%`;

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp, it is done at 50% 50% by default.

Comment: w3schools is *often* inaccurate and a *horrible* source to use.

Comment: Okay, will do. MDN still says that it is done at 50% 50% https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: @Scott No. The default for normal elements is 50% 50%. Only SVG elements in some cases have the default at 0 0. See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform-origin

Answer (score 1):

Set `background-position` to `center` and `transform-origin: 50% 50%`.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwuwfequ/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform-origin:` in the CSS to set the origin point....

```
div{
  background:url('https://s32.postimg.org/4ze7aqwed/close.png') no-repeat center center;
  height:16px;
  width:16px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform:rotate(0);
  transition:transform .3s ease
}
div:hover{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform:rotate(90deg)
}
```

And center the background image.

[Fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/qwuwfequ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

your image is not centered . just do url('https://s32.postimg.org/4ze7aqwed/close.png') no-repeat center center;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div{
  background:url('https://s32.postimg.org/4ze7aqwed/close.png') no-repeat center center;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  transform:rotate(0);
  transition:transform .3s ease


}
div:hover{
  transform:rotate(90deg);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `background-position : center;` to div CSS to set the background image position....